# Google authentification with "devise" fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-oauth, omniauth

I want to create a GOOGLE authentification in my app. So in set up "omniauth" and "devise" correctly (I think). In my layout folder in "_header.html.erb" view :

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>Signed in as <%= current_user.name %>. Not you?
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path,:method => :delete %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to "Sign in with Google", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
<% end %>
```

When I try to connect I click on the link given by this code that open new page, I choose my google account then accept the rights and this redirect me to the same page. (where the link is). My database is fill by the account information correctly.

But like the code say I want after the connection that the header print the name of the connected account and this is not the case. It print again "Sign In with google".

Moreover I want to redirect on another page just after the connection. How do i do that.
Maybe i must define `user_signed_in?` method, if it's the case, where and how ?

current_user is define in application_controller like this :

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

In my user model I have only that :

```
def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.info
    user = User.where(:provider => access_token.provider, :uid =>     access_token.uid ).first

    unless user
      #registered_user = User.where(:email => access_token.info.email).first

      #if registered_user
      #  return registered_user
      #else
        user = User.create(
          name: data["name"],
          provider:access_token.provider,
          email: data["email"],
          uid: access_token.uid ,
          password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
        )
      #end

   end
   p user
   user
end
```

Hope you could help me.

Thanks in Advance.

PS : If you want some code, simply say comment and I will edit the question with the part of the code.

Comment: can you please share your from_omniauth class method which I guess would be there inside your user model.

Comment: I edit but i don't have from_omniauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create a OmniauthCallbacksController and Add the following code**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def all
    p env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = "You are in..!!! Go to edit profile to see the status for the accounts"
      sign_in_and_redirect(user)
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    #handle you logic here..
    #and delegate to super.
    super
  end

  alias_method :google_oauth2, :all
end
```

**In your config/routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

**Create a Authorization model**

```
rails g model Authorization
```

**In migration add following code**

```
class CreateAuthorizations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :authorizations do |t|
      t.string :provider
      t.string :uid
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :token
      t.string :secret
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

then

```
rake db:migrate
```

**In your models/authorization.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**In your models/user.rb**

```
has_many :authorizations

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  authorization = Authorization.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid.to_s).first_or_initialize
  authorization.token = auth.credentials.token
  if authorization.user.blank?
    user = User.where('email = ?', auth["info"]["email"]).first
    if user.blank?
     user = User.new
     user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,10]
     user.email = auth.info.email
     user.save
    end
   authorization.user_id = user.id
   if auth.provider == "google_oauth2"
    authorization.secret = auth.credentials.refresh_token !auth.credentials.refresh_token.blank?
    authorization.secret = auth.credentials.secret 
   end
  end
  authorization.save
  authorization.user
end
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but now i have a problem with mogoid. When I click on login with google I havhe this error : `Could not connect to a primary node for replica set #<Moped::Cluster:64483908 @seeds=[<Moped::Node resolved_address=nil>]>` i do the migration with active_record and I have an active_record database. I ha already configured mongoid in the yml.